# How to deduplicate dataframe but keep and merge data from one differing column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe/excel file where there are two rows for each unique object, where all columns for an object have equal values except for one column, where values are different. I would like to get rid of duplicate rows but keep all data.

So it looks something like:

```
C1,  C2,     C3, C4;
ID1, Value1, A1, one;
ID1, Value1, A1, two;
ID2, Value2, B2, three;
ID2, Value2, B2, four;
```

I would like to merge the repeating rows into one row for each unique C1, but merge all the values into one field from C4.

So the end result would be:

```
C1,  C2,     C3, C4;
ID1, Value1, A1, onetwo;
ID2, Value2, B2, threefour;
```

Any pointers? I need to fix a Script for a data processing job for a project where I work with different programming languages, my only experience with python and pandas is from university a few years back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.groupby and agg

```
df.groupby(['C1','C2','C3']).agg({'C4': lambda x: ' '.join(x)})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm with aggregating the values for C4, however, the returning dataframe only has C4 as a column? Is there a simple way for returning the unmerged columns also?